# Cannot start activity without getting fatal exceptions

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting ready to develop my first app. Had some minor success yesterday, but
today the app crashes everytime I try to pass and display an intent in a new activity.
As I could not find my mistake I started from scratch using the google "myFirstApp" tutorial,
only to find out I had the same crashes starting an activity, despite
following exactly the instructions.
I do not find my mistake, so I politely ask you to help me find the error.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Activity I pass the intent to:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        setContentView(textView);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
03-27 19:32:07.786: D/libEGL(3929): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
03-27 19:32:07.796: D/libEGL(3929): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
03-27 19:32:07.796: D/libEGL(3929): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
03-27 19:32:07.816: D/OpenGLRenderer(3929): Enabling debug mode 0
03-27 19:32:11.470: E/FragmentManager(3929): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{41c05db0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-27 19:32:11.470: E/FragmentManager(3929): Activity state:
03-27 19:32:11.470: D/FragmentManager(3929):   Local FragmentActivity 41bf9838 State:
03-27 19:32:11.470: D/FragmentManager(3929):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
03-27 19:32:11.470: D/FragmentManager(3929):     mLoadersStarted=false
03-27 19:32:11.470: D/FragmentManager(3929):   Active Fragments in 41bf9a70:
03-27 19:32:11.490: D/FragmentManager(3929):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{41c05db0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-27 19:32:11.490: D/FragmentManager(3929):       mFragmentId=#7f05003c mContainerId=#7f05003c mTag=null
03-27 19:32:11.490: D/FragmentManager(3929):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
03-27 19:32:11.490: D/FragmentManager(3929):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
03-27 19:32:11.490: D/FragmentManager(3929):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
03-27 19:32:11.490: D/FragmentManager(3929):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
03-27 19:32:11.490: D/FragmentManager(3929):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{41bf9a70 in DisplayMessageActivity{41bf9838}}
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):       mActivity=com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity@41bf9838
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):   Added Fragments:
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{41c05db0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):   FragmentManager misc state:
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):     mActivity=com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity@41bf9838
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@41bf9ae8
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):   View Hierarchy:
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41bfb3e8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):       android.widget.LinearLayout{41bfba50 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-27 19:32:11.500: D/FragmentManager(3929):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{41bfc5d8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #10203f9 android:id/action_bar_container}
03-27 19:32:11.510: D/FragmentManager(3929):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{41bfcb20 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #10203fa android:id/action_bar}
03-27 19:32:11.510: D/FragmentManager(3929):             android.widget.LinearLayout{41c00de0 G....... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-27 19:32:11.510: D/FragmentManager(3929):               android.widget.ImageView{41c01a48 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020255 android:id/up}
03-27 19:32:11.510: D/FragmentManager(3929):               android.widget.LinearLayout{41c01d48 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-27 19:32:11.510: D/FragmentManager(3929):                 android.widget.TextView{41c020b0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020268 android:id/action_bar_title}
03-27 19:32:11.510: D/FragmentManager(3929):                 android.widget.TextView{41c02e20 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020269 android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
03-27 19:32:11.510: D/FragmentManager(3929):             com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{41bfdec8 VFE...C. ... 0,0-0,0}
03-27 19:32:11.520: D/FragmentManager(3929):               android.widget.ImageView{41bff3e0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020255 android:id/up}
03-27 19:32:11.520: D/FragmentManager(3929):               android.widget.ImageView{41bff6e0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102002c android:id/home}
03-27 19:32:11.520: D/FragmentManager(3929):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{41c03438 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #10203fb android:id/action_context_bar}
03-27 19:32:11.520: D/FragmentManager(3929):         android.widget.FrameLayout{41c03950 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
03-27 19:32:11.520: D/FragmentManager(3929):           android.widget.TextView{41c05590 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-27 19:32:11.530: D/dalvikvm(3929): GC_CONCURRENT freed 189K, 10% free 9571K/10567K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 52ms
03-27 19:32:11.530: D/FragmentManager(3929):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{41c03d40 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #10203fc android:id/split_action_bar}
03-27 19:32:11.530: D/AndroidRuntime(3929): Shutting down VM
03-27 19:32:11.530: W/dalvikvm(3929): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411d52a0)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{41c05db0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{41c05db0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5057)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2065)
03-27 19:32:11.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     ... 11 more
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_display_message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_display_message.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Greetings,
John

Comment: post `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id
>   0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment
>   PlaceholderFragment{41c05db0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}

You do not have a `ViewGroup` with the id `container` in `activity_main.xml`.

But you have

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment());
```

Have a `ViewGroup` such as `FrameLayout` with id `container` in your xml

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Have the below in `activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
    }

}
```

No need for `activity_display_message.xml`. remove all unwanted code

Comment: why do I have these lines in the first place. I did not add them

Comment: @user3469968 then remove them if you don't want fragment in the first place. the ide added it for you i guess

Comment: @user3469968 you can also change `extends ActionBarActivity` to just `Activity` if you are supporting api level 11 and above

Comment: **"why do I have these lines in the first place. I did not add them"** : There was a post here on StackOverflow recently which might be related. The latest Android dev tools automatically creates a project which assumes using a `Fragment` and container for that `Fragment` - this is causing a lot of confusion for people. Sorry I can't find a link to it at the moment but if I do I'll post it here. Basically if you're not using the `Fragment` code, rip it out.

Comment: ripping it out caused my app to just show a blank page
rather then it's layout. should I maybe use another target
api?

Comment: @user3469968 sorry its not the ide its the ADT tool. and yes you get rid of fragment related code and the fragment xml

Comment: Thank you very Much. ripping out all that fragment code did infact help. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when the id of the view in which you want to add or replace a fragment does not exist in the layout that you inflate in your activity.

So on the code you post, i think (I must see `R.layout.activity_display_message` xml to be sure) the problem is that the `container` view does not exist on this layout, so in this line:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

The exception is thrown at `DisplayMessageActivity`.

Comment: I do not have a container view in the main activity either. I works there, i dont get it
edit: I do have the line android:id="@+id/container"
in my activity_display_message xml

Comment: also, on DisplayMessageActivity, you have this line:

Comment: setContentView(textView); just before trying to add the fragment, so the view of the fragment is no longer a linear layout and its a text view, maybe this is the real problem.

Comment: making the setContentView(textView) a comment does not throw the exception! but that way i cannot pass the intent.
where exactly do you mean I should place the line?
Putting it above the if-clause did not help

Comment: In fact you should not initialize the TextView using new, you should search it on the layout like this:First put an id to the TextView on the layout, for example: txtMessage, then in the Activity find using: TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);, using this you do not need to add the contentView with the TextView, this method should only be use to set the main layout of the Activity or Fragment, for all the other views (on the layout) you should use findByid method

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread because I was having the same problem. After trying various things suggested, without success, I went back to the tutorial and read the instructions very carefully. That solved the problem for me. Though I do think the instructions for editing the code in DisplayMessageActivity#onCreate() could be clearer.

I removed some of the generated code, and ended up with what is shown in the section titled "Display the Message":

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

And it worked!